# .NET 7 and UseEndPoints()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-7.0, asp.net-core-7.0

I am trying to convert a .NET Core 3.1 project to .NET 7.

When I use this in my `Program.cs` class:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

It gives me this message:

> Suggest using top level route registrations UseEndpoints

Then, I clicked on `Show potential fixes` in Visual Studio and it suggests this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    _ = endpoints.MapRazorPages();

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Which looks the same to me.

In .NET 7, what should I do if I need to use RazorPages()?

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

AFAIK it should work as is but the warning suggests to register the routes at the top-level of a minimal hosting application, i.e.:

```cs
app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

See the [ASP0014: Suggest using top level route registrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/diagnostics/asp0014?view=aspnetcore-7.0) code analysis rule.

Comment: Oh ok, so I don't need `UseEndpoints` and I can just change `endpoints.MapControllerRoute` to `app.MapControllerRoute` ?  Thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I am using for using endpoints.

```
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
      endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
             name: "areas",
             pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
      endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
              name: "default",
              pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
      endpoints.MapRazorPages();
  });
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Well actually not really. This question has a good answer. Your answer is just showing the same case the OP originally had.

Comment: There is a difference in the API used and the order of things that matters. I am using Endppoints on app not MapControl on app also the areas should be before the default, and in my case I am showing MapRazor at the end not at first.  What was suggested was the ideal way in earlier versions before UseEndpoint was introduced.