# How to merge Startup.cs into Program.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

I'm new to ASP.NET Core. I'm using ASP.NET Core 7. I read that in  ASP.NET Core 7 they got rid of `Startup.cs`. Can someone show me how to merge `Startup.cs` into `Program.cs` in this example.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph

Comment: "I read that in asp.net core 7 they got rid of Startup.cs" nope. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#faq

Comment: That's good to know. But they say The new hosting model is the preferred way to host new apps using .NET 6 and later. As I'm learning, I want to know how to move code to Program.cs from Startup.cs.

Comment: NOT a dupe but related https://stackoverflow.com/q/74691624/125981

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I read that in ASP.NET Core 7 they got rid of Startup.cs.

Not exactly. ASP.NET Core 6 introduced a new so called minimal hosting model (which is used by the default template). But you are free to keep [the generic hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-7.0) if you want.

> How to merge Startup.cs into Program.cs

In short - move everything from `ConfigureServices` to before `var app = builder.Build();` call and everything from `Configure` - after it (check out code generated by the default template). To setup services you can use `builder.Services`, configuration is accessible from both `builder` and `app` via correspondingly named property and use `app` to perform the calls from `Startup.Configure`.

See also:

- [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 5.0 to 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)
- [Code samples migrated to the new minimal hosting model in ASP.NET Core 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
- [ASP.NET Core 6 how to access Configuration during startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69722872/asp-net-core-6-how-to-access-configuration-during-startup/69722959#69722959)
- [.NET 7 and UseEndPoints()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74691624/net-7-and-useendpoints/74692760#74692760)

Comment: Where should I put a function like GetSecretFromKeyVault? Can I include functions like these in Program.cs?

Comment: @joegreen you can put it in your `Program.cs` file. It will become a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) so it should be placed before any class declarations if any there (in the Program.cs).